# Create layer from CSV with a bunch of KML polygons

Tags: qgis, csv, kml

I have a CSV with 3 fields Id,Name,KML polygon. I want to create layers from this polygons in QGIS. I've tried to add delimeter text layer with geometry definition as WKT or without any geometry definition. The best I obtain text layer with one of the attributes - string with KML polygon.

Example of CSV line:

```
65013,ANSOST,"\<Polygon> \<outerBoundaryIs> \<LinearRing> \<coordinates>0.108731980044606,43.422308551893501 0.105164688900528,43.42521109435652 0.100863486900872,43.43948222925345 0.109087938796386,43.442015732120169 0.11688292307137,43.439081575310354 0.115993569589449,43.422817285305129 0.108731980044606,43.422308551893501\</coordinates> \</LinearRing> \</outerBoundaryIs> \</Polygon>"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

###### Convert KML to WKT

The following script is [jpinilla](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/40175/jpinilla)'s answer implemented in PyQGIS. It can be run in the Script Editor of the Python Console.

It does the following:

1. Takes your original CSV as the input
2. Fixes the formatting of the KML string
3. Creates a temporary QgsVectorLayer of the KML
4. Converts the geometry to WKT
5. Writes a new CSV with WKT instead of KML, this can be imported into QGIS as a valid Vector Layer.

⚠️ Warning

It does not handle feature collections, or whatever the KML equivalent name is. It is based purely on the sample you provided.

```py
import csv

p = QgsProject.instance()

path_csv = r"path\to\input\csv.csv"
path_converted_csv = r"path\to\save\the\converted.csv"


def format_kml(kml_string):
    # function to properly format the KML data in the CSV
    header = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
                <Placemark>
                <name></name>\n"""
                
    footer = """\n</Placemark>
                </kml>"""
    
    new_kml_string = header + kml_string + footer
    
    return new_kml_string

# get the CSV rows as a list
with open(path_csv, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    rows = list(reader)

# variable to hold the converted data
data = []
for row in rows:
    attributes = row[:2]

    # isolate KML string
    kml = row[-1]
    
    # fix the kml by providing a header and proper tags
    formatted_kml = format_kml(kml)

    # write a temporary KML file
    with open('temp.kml', 'w+') as temp_kml:
        temp_kml.write(formatted_kml)

    # create a QgsVectorLayer using the temporary KML as the data source
    temp_kml_lyr = QgsVectorLayer('temp.kml', 'temp kml layer')

    # get the first (and only) feature from the layer
    feat = list(temp_kml_lyr.getFeatures())[0]

    # get the geometry and convert it to WKT
    geom = feat.geometry()
    wkt = geom.asWkt()

    # append the WKT string to the existing attributes
    attributes.append(wkt)

    # append the new row to the data list
    data.append(attributes)

# write the data to a new CSV
with open(path_converted_csv, 'w+') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

###### Add the converted CSV as a layer

Import the new CSV as a layer using `Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer...`

Uncheck `First record has field names` (unless you decide to add field names, there are none in your sample).

Select `Well-Known Text` as the *Geometry Definition*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works flawlessly. Thank You.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck going forwards.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS cannot directly interpret KML format within a CSV file, so I suggest you:

1. Convert KML to WKT (Well-Known Text).
2. Update Your CSV to replace the KML columns with the new WKT geometries.
3. Import into QGIS your CSV file.

Your CSV file should be imported as a polygon layer in QGIS.